# What is OpenGL maximum texture size with NPOT textures?

Tags: image, opengl, graphics, textures

I know I can use this code to retreive the maximum texture size of a GPU:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &size, 0);
```

I can also get the maximum texture buffer size with:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE, &size, 0);
```

The problem is that I want to create an atlas to pack font characters and 2D atlas are more complex and space in the atlas can be lost by filling them without planning where to fit every chararcter. So, I am using a 1 dimensional atlas to store text characters:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1py9l2hEk3-fJzqyMeF6P2ajrNs3CFDFj

Can I exceed `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` if the texture buffer size is smaller than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE`? The textures are NPOT so that made me ask this question (because maximum texture size is `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` squared and the textures does not reach `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` in the Y axis).

**EDIT**

To make the question clear, can I create a texture which width > `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` but the height isn't and the texture buffer does not exceed `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE`. Ex:

if `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` is 8192, creating a texture with dimensions of 10000 x 40. It doesn't exceed `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE` which is 8192 squared but it exceeds the side maximum.

Comment: "*So, I am using a 1 dimensional atlas to store text characters:*" So, you're making a memory-for-performance tradeoff, then. Also, I don't understand the nature of your question. The maximum size of the texture depends on what kind of texture it is. But there's no such thing as an "NPOT texture"; that's not a texture type.

Comment: I dnt think you can do that basically as per specs if textures size is greater its texels will be clamped to implementation dependent value which is GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE.

Comment: I edited the question. I think it's a bit clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` governs the dimensions of 1D and 2D textures of all forms. It does not care about how much *storage* a texture takes up; it's about the size of its dimensions.

`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE` has nothing to do with the size of a texture's *storage* either (not directly). It is a limit on the dimension of a [buffer texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture), which are not 1D or 2D textures. It only matters if your texture is of the `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` type, which is distinct from `GL_TEXTURE_1D` or `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

And none of these matters has anything to do with NPOT textures. That is merely the removal of the restriction of having texture dimensions being a power of two.